# Error: No network specified. Cannot determine current network

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, truffle

Truffle react-box not working as expected with default setup (with ganache and metamask)

I [download and run ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases) then I followed the first 4 steps in the [readme](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box) and when I get to truffle migrate it says 'Error: No network specified. Cannot determine current network.' in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OSX 10.13.3 I went into the `truffle.js` file in the root folder and changed it to

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 7545,
      network_id: '*'
    }
  }
};
```

[image]

`npm run start` in the terminal and everything works fine. Make sure you have [ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases) running in the background though.

Also, make sure that the rpc server in ganache matches the host and port in the truffle file you just updated.

[image]

Comment: details on connecting metamask to ganache can be found here http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/truffle-with-metamask